# How to restrict microsoft inkoverlay draw in input controls like (textbox, checkbox)?

Tags: c#, .net, microsoft.ink

I want to restrict `InkOverlay` drawing in textbox and checkbox, but I need to draw in label. How to achieve this.

If I set

```
theInkOverlay.AttachMode =InkOverlayAttachMode.Behind;
```

It is applying for all the controls. I need to draw above on the label and picture controls.

Answer (score 0):

InkOverlay objects attach to a window, and are either above or below that window.  Therefore, your best option is to put two child windows on your dialog/main window, and put your textbox/checkboxes in one window and put the ink overlay on the second window.